# Extract number from within a string

Tags: java, regex

I know its been answered already, but I am struggling to extract the number from the given string

```
internal-pdf://2586543536/Homan-2014-RNA tertiary structure analysis by.pd
```

I need to extract "2586543536"

I am using following regex, which I am sure is incorrect.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("internal-pdf://\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Comment: You didn't create any capturing group in your regex. To create one you will need to wrap part which it should represent with parenthesis, in your case `(\\d+)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap `\d+` with a capturing group and run the matcher with `m.find()` to find a partial match:

```
String value = "internal-pdf://2586543536/Homan-2014-RNA tertiary structure analysis by.pd";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("internal-pdf://(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); 
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/bNJUYd).